# SQL: how to self-reference the output of an INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to be able to run a self-inner join on the output of a query.
Performing an self INNER JOIN, in the simplest case, is easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM A a1 INNER JOIN
A a2 ON
a1.key = a2.key
```

The problem is that I need to do this self-inner join *on the output of another inner join*. Something like

```
SELECT * 

FROM DATA.A A INNER JOIN
DATA.B B 
ON A.key = B.key output /* output is the dataset I am interested in */


INNER JOIN

(FROM DATA.A A INNER JOIN
DATA.B B 
ON A.key = B.key output2) /* same code to get output, so that I can self reference */

ON
OUTPUT.key_alt = OUTPUT2.key_alt
```

Is it possible to do so? I cannot store `output` in my database.

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: what you can do is dissect your output select statement so you can easily read it. at this stage i can't figure out what you want to do

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Microsoft SQL (sql-server) and MySQL are different products. You can't have both tags in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server:

I prefer to use a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) for this sort of thing. It keeps things a more readable in my opinion.

```
with cte as (
  select * 
  from data.A as A 
    inner join data.B as B
      on A.key = B.key
)
select ...
from cte as o
  inner join cte as i
    on o.key = i.key
```

You can do achieve this with standard subqueries though.

```
select o.*
from (
  select * 
  from data.A as A 
    inner join data.B as B
      on A.key = B.key
  ) as o
  inner join (
  select * 
  from data.A as A 
    inner join data.B as B
      on A.key = B.key
  ) as i
    on o.key = i.key
```

Comment: so in essence this is what I did ? :D

Comment: @Noobie It looks like what you were trying to do with your psuedo-code. If you share more detail about your actual problem, there would may be other ways that are simpler or more appropriate than this.